# How to vertically wrap content with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three divs inside a flexbox container.

I would like the three `divs` to be displayed as follows:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|     +-----------------+-----------------+     |
|     |                 |                 |     |
|     |                 |                 |     |
|     +-----------------+-----------------+     |
|                                               |
|     +-----------------------------------+     |
|     |                                   |     |
|     |                                   |     |
|     +-----------------------------------+     |
|                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

so the container will have to adapt vertically to its content but only to its content, not more than that.

I am getting big white spaces between the `divs` and the container is getting the 100% of the `height` of its parent, though.

I tried without putting `height` property to the container and setting `height: auto;` but neither of them worked.

Here is the code I have:

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

#container{
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: auto;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 max-width: 450px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

#div1{
 width: 50%;
 height: 155px;
 background-color: blue;
}

#div2{
    width: 50%;
    height: 155px;  
    background-color: red;
}

#div3{
    width: 70%;
    height: 155px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Make it bigger to see the white spaces between the divs.

How can I make the container shrink-wrap the content and not be 100% height of its parent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a flex container, an initial setting is `align-content: stretch`.

This causes multiple lines of flex items  to distribute themselves across the full length of the container.

Override this setting with `align-content: flex-start` on `#container`.

---

To make the `#container` shrink-wrap its contents vertically, you need to remove this rule:

```
#container { bottom: 0; }
```

Because `#container` is absolutely positioned, and there is no parent element that is positioned, which would establish the containing block for `#container`, the default containing block becomes the ***initial containing block*** or, the viewport.

That's why the container is stretching from top to bottom, as illustrated by the black border you applied. Once your remove `bottom: 0` the container will act more like `height: auto`.

Learn more about CSS positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thank you! It is very close, but not exactly what I am looking for. It still does not adapt the height of the container to its content. Just put the content together (one of the two approachs). Look it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4dfLv48y/).

Comment: I had `bottom: 0` because I wanted to have the container both vertically and horizontally centered on the screen. I guess that I have to find another way now to center it.

Comment: To center the container on the screen, just use another flex container: https://jsfiddle.net/rf15p2vw/2/

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for reply too late. I thought about it but I also was doubting about if it was a good idea to put a `flex` on the `body` tag or not. Now you clarify my mind. Thank you again :)

Comment: You're welcome. I found no problems using `flex` on `body` element. Works fine for me.

Comment: Sure. You are one of my best helpers :)