# How to remove border from elements in the last row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

My layout is something like this (I'm typing a simplified version with inline styles instead of classes)

```css
.qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row">
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This basically renders something like this:

[image]

**My questions is:**

**How do I get rid of the border in the last row?**

Comment: I think nth-last-child would be able to help you https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/

Comment: Yes I was thinking along the same lines but that only targets the bottom right div. I need it to target both last row divs

Comment: Just add: .qa:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  border: 0;
}

Comment: @bea: your's is the right answer! Put it as an answer and you'll get upvoted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a negative bottom margin to your elements then hide the overflow. This will hide the unwanted borders.

```css
.qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  margin-top:1px; /*to rectify the bottom margin, we can also consider padding-bottom*/
  
  /*irrelevant styles*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex:1 1 40%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br>Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This trick should work even if the number of element in a row is different from 2:

```css
.qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  margin-top:1px;
  
  
  /*irrelevant styles*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex:1 1 20%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br> answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br> answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will also work with a reponsive layout where the number of columns can change on small screens:

```css
.qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  margin-top:1px;
  
  
  /*irrelevant styles*/
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex:1 1 20%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  .qa {
    flex:1 1 30%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width:400px) {
  .qa {
    flex:1 1 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br> answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" >
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer<br> answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great out of the box thinking! and it covers both flex row and columns. That's why I love SO, you get to learn so much! thanks

Comment: @supersan yes exactly ;) it will cover all the different configuration and more important the responsive part as I am sure that your layout will change to one column for example on small screens.

Comment: .wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
} has often negative side-effects ... only as a remark ...

Answer (score 10):

## 1: Use Another CSS class

We can create another CSS class which removes any styling form an existence element

```
.no-border {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Then add this class to the html element e.g.

```
  <div class="qa no-border" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
```

## 2: Use CSS pseudo selector

```
.qa:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.qa:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: they are called pseudo classes (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Comment: never realized it would always be the last and second last element. the layout makes it look like it's the 3rd element and 6th element. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Don't think about it as `border-bottom`.

Think about it as `border-top` and exclude the first two elements.

So instead of this:

```
.qa { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

Try this:

```
.qa + .qa + .qa { border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```css
.qa + .qa + .qa {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row">
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The [**next-sibling combinator**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) (`+`) targets an element that is immediately preceded by another element, and both share the same parent.

So `.qa + .qa` would target only `.qa` elements that are preceded by one `.qa` element.

`.qa + .qa + .qa` targets only `.qa` elements that are preceded by two `.qa` elements.

---

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
.qa:nth-child(n + 3) { border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```css
.qa:nth-child(n + 3) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row">
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Your first solution is absolutely unreadable. Your second option I like.

Comment: @Raz0rwire, what don't you understand?

Comment: @Micheal_B Understanding it now is not the problem, looking at the code 6 months from now could introduce some head scratching. Maybe I was being a little dramatic..

Answer (score 4):

judging by your layout, the items are numbered:

```
  [1]  [2]
  [3]  [4]
  [5]  [6]
```

now, you can either:

- remove border-bottom from 5th & 6th items

```
.qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.qa:nth-of-type(5),
.qa:nth-of-type(6) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

- add border-bottom to 1st-4th items:

```
.qa:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

- do similar math but for adding `border-top`

---

you can also flip the flex direction to make it more "reasonable" but also requires a fixed height (needed for wrapping, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416977/how-to-vertically-wrap-content-with-flexbox)):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

which numbers items in a different orientation:

```
  [1]  [4]
  [2]  [5]
  [3]  [6]
```

now you reomove border-bottom on every 3rd item:

```
.qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.qa:nth-of-type(3n) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

---

there are more complex fixes as well. for instance, you can group items in rows and apply border on row based selectors. This will be closest to what you really intended in the first place:

```
.row .qa {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.row:last-of-type .qa {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a `:after` pseudo Element in parent container of .qa (make sure your parent container is set to `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`)

Css for .qa parent element

```
{
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: /* set this to your (bottom padding of container + bottom margin of .qa box + border width)  */
    background: #fff; /* match this with your parent element background colour*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `border-top` and remove the first two with the `:nth-child` CSS selector. Like this:

```css
.qa {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.qa:nth-child(-n+2) {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row">
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like adding a rule when you know you're immediately going to overwrite it, so here's a slightly different version of aridlehoover's answer with only one CSS rule.

```css
.qa:not(:nth-child(-n+2)) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row">
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="qa" style="width:50%;">
    <div>Question</div>
    <div>Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```